# Logitech G25 Racing Wheel

Tags: 12.04, games

How can I set up a Logitech G25 Racing Wheel in Ubuntu 12.04?

Is there a driver or other tool avaiable?

I'll be using it in Speed Dreams.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LTWheelConf](https://github.com/thk/LTWheelConf) to change various settings of the Logitech racing wheels

- Driving Force
- Momo Racing
- Momo Force
- Driving Force Pro
- Driving Force GT
- G25
- G27

Available options:

- set wheel to "native" mode (support separate axes and clutch pedal, H shifter, full 900 degree rotation)
- Set wheel rotation range
- Set autocenter force and rampspeed
- Set ForceFeedback gain

### Compile and install

You can easily compile LTWheelConf using the following commands:

**Get some dependencies**

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev git
```

**Download the source**

```
git clone https://github.com/thk/LTWheelConf.git
```

**Build the source**

```
cd LTWheelConf
make
```

**Install**

```
cp ltwheelconf /usr/local/bin/
```

You should now have an executable named `ltwheelconf`.

**List all found/supported devices**

```
sudo ltwheelconf --list
```

Supported wheel shortname values:

- 'DF'   (Driving Force)
- 'MR'   (Momo Racing)
- 'MF'   (Momo Force)
- 'DFP'  (Driving Force Pro)
- 'DFGT' (Driving Force GT)
- 'G25'  (G25) <-- This is, obviously, the shortname of your steering wheel
- 'G27'  (G27)

**Set wheel to native mode**

```
sudo ltwheelconf --wheel <your-wheel-shortname> --nativemode
```

**Set wheel rotation range of 900 degrees**

```
sudo ltwheelconf --wheel <your-wheel-shortname> --range 900
```

### Examples:

Put wheel into native mode:

```
$ sudo ltwheelconf --wheel G25 --nativemode
```

Set wheel rotation range to 540 degree:

```
$ sudo ltwheelconf --wheel G25 --range 540
```

Set moderate autocenter:

```
$ sudo ltwheelconf --wheel G25 --autocenter 100 --rampspeed 1
```

Disable autocenter completely:

```
$ sudo ltwheelconf --wheel G25 --autocenter 0 --rampspeed 0
```

Set native mode, disable autocenter and set wheel rotation range of 900 degrees in one call:

```
$ sudo ltwheelconf --wheel G25 --nativemode --range 900 --autocenter 0 --rampspeed 0
```

To test and calibrate the steering wheel you can use **jstest-gtk**

### Add UDEV rule

It is possible to add a rule to UDEV to automatically invoke LTWheelConf when the steering wheel is connected.

This can be done using the following command (use the correct shortname instead of  `<your-wheel-shortname>`!):

```
echo 'ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c294", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/ltwheelconf --wheel <your-wheel-shortname> --nativemode --range 900"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/90-logitech-wheel.rules
```

Now you need to restart UDEV:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

Comment: okay, thank you. and how can i setup forced feedback now?

Comment: Wish I could +1 this more than once. Can also confirm it works perfectly on Ubuntu 14.04LTS